# API to get current balance $$/tokens

Tags: openai-api

How to get the current balance as seen in screenshot using API? I went through every page on OpenAI website, could not find anything related.

[image: openai account page screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

for now ,2023.4.4, I can't use api-key for url(https://api.openai.com/dashboard/billing/credit_grants). Maybe you need use selenium, after login in ,get your headers key, "authorization", instead of api-key content.

edit :

> I found another way to get openai balance, It works, you just need use api-key. you can use "https://api.openai.com/dashboard/billing/subscription" to get your "hard_limit_usd", use "https://api.openai.com/dashboard/billing/usage?start_date=2023-01-01&end_date=2023-04-04" to get your total usage. Just do minus.

Answer (score 3):

Since 2023-04-01

You call api with session key

```
curl -X GET https://api.openai.com/dashboard/billing/credit_grants \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer sess-xxxx"
```

You can find session key with F12 on https://platform.openai.com/account/usage

API response:

```
{
  "object": "credit_summary",
  "total_granted": 0.0,
  "total_used": 0.0,
  "total_available": 0.0,
  "grants": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": []
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a long term solution since at your next login you get an other session key

Comment: @Davide the session is long enough while this is a fallback solution

Answer (score 0):

#### Balance and expiration date

api

```
GET https://api.openai.com/dashboard/billing/credit_grants
```

example

```
curl --location 'https://api.openai.com/dashboard/billing/credit_grants' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer sk-***'
```

result

```
{
    "object": "credit_summary",
    "total_granted": 18.0,
    "total_used": 10.73756,
    "total_available": 7.26244,
    "grants": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
            {
                "object": "credit_grant",
                "id": "2235a2ca-***",
                "grant_amount": 18.0,
                "used_amount": 10.73756,
                "effective_at": 1676332800.0,
                "expires_at": 1685577600.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct anymore. When you try to use secret_key for granted credits it tells you `{ "error": { "message": "Your request to GET /dashboard/billing/credit_grants must be made with a session key (that is, it can only be made from the browser). You made it with the following key type: secret.", "type": "server_error", "param": null, "code": null } }`

Comment: This is not correct anymore, see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your `token` status is passed though each response.

---

From the OpenAI API FAQ:

> ##### How do I check my token usage? <sup>[[link]](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6614209-how-do-i-check-my-token-usage)</sup>
>
> 1. **Usage dashboard**
>    ...
> 2. **Usage data from the API response**
>
>    You can also access token usage data through the API. ***Token usage information is now included in responses from completions, edits, and embeddings endpoints***. Information on prompt and completion tokens is contained in the "usage" key:

---

So an example response could include the following `usage` key:

```json
"usage": {
   "prompt_tokens":5,
   "completion_tokens":5,
   "total_tokens":10
}
```